# Legend in gelman.plot

Tags: r, legend

I need help with the command `gelman.plot` of the package `coda`.

I would like to know if it is possible to increase the size of the legend (that indicates the median and 97.5% upper confidence limit).

I managed to increase the size of labels, title and axis values, but not of the legend.

In case this is not possible, I would like to know if there is a way to not display the legend at all.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve it on my own and the only solution I found was to modify (temporarily) the function ''gelman.plot'' in the package ''coda'' using the command ''trace(gelman.plot, edit = TRUE)'' and then removing the part concerning the legend.

I post this in case anyone needs it.